# Using AdMob ID of published app

Tags: android, google-play, package, admob

Is it possible to use AdMob ID of a published app on play store with another app, which I won't publish on Play Store but will be available to download from my website?

Do I need to use same package name for the non-play store app?

Can AdMob monitor or verify that one ID is being used by a non-play store app.

I have seen examples of people using one AdMob ID for all there published play store apps, I want to confirm if that is the case with non-published apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the admob ID you use for the unpublished apps is ***linked to*** an app on the play store, you wouldn't have to worry much.

Also, since it isn't against the rules to use one admob ID for multiple apps, you can use the same package name.

You should [check this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-admob-ads-sdk/gNZ6xD0IXw8/x6axuJEmXK8J). According to Eric, the particular app store doesn't matter, so you should have no problem using the admob ID with non-published apps. Just make sure the admob ID used is ***linked to*** a published app.

We use the same strategy for most of our apps that are only published on our site, Samsung, and Amazon stores.

What you have to worry about is invalid activities such as click fraud, very high CTR etc